# Running C++ program invisible

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, keylogger

```
void Stealth()
{
   HWND Stealth;
   AllocConsole();
   Stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
   ShowWindow(Stealth,0);
}
```

I am calling this funtion from my main method in a C++ console application to hide the console window. It does it, but when I run the program the console window flashes for a split second before disappearing.

I want to run the program without this window flashing fully invisible. How to do this?

Comment: Side note: there's a `GetConsoleWindow` function. I have to question the `AllocConsole` call in the first place, though. Just don't make a console window if you don't want it?

Comment: Make it a windowed application (as opposed to console one), then simply don't create any windows.

Comment: Any sample code would be appreciated!

Comment: There is no code. It's just compiling it that way. But if you already have a console application, why the `AllocConsole` call? The first sentence in the remarks section for that function is *A process can be associated with only one console, so the AllocConsole function fails if the calling process already has a console.* It also says *Console applications are initialized with a console, unless they are created as detached processes*

Comment: So I just have to delete the `AllocConsole();` line?

Comment: If your app uses `WinMain` or `wWinMain` as its entrypoint, this defaults to the Windows subsystem. If it uses `main` or `wmain`, this defaults to the console subsystem, and thus will automatically allocate a console window if it doesn't inherit one from its parent.